# Can an invitation letter have no entry/exit dates?

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, us-visa

Sometimes we need to visit the company's HQ in the USA, but we don't have information about the dates more than 2-3 weeks in advance. And visa waiting time here can be up to 2 years. So I wonder if the letter of invitation without exact dates can be accepted by the consulate?

Comment: What is  your citizenship ? What class of visa are we talking about ?

Comment: @Hilmar for the visa, see the tags. Citizenship - does it change the answer to this question?

Comment: It changes the answer if you don’t need a visa, at least.

Comment: @user626528 your citizenship can definitely affect the process

Comment: @Midavalo I know that, but I really don't think that it can change the answer to _this_ question. Or at least it shouldn't.

Comment: @user626528, it most likely should not but often it still does. Do not argue but provide one or a few nationalities for the people in the know to base their answers on.

Comment: Are you asking if you can *complete the online form and make an appointment* without having the specific dates? Or *attend the interview with a letter of invitation without exact dates*? Or both?

Comment: @Traveller I mean the letter of invitation without specific dates. I already have a visa appointment scheduled (started it couple years ago), but the event that I originally was going to visit already is in the past.

Comment: @Willeke well, in this case I can give the answer myself: it's very bad citizenship, and you'd better avoid it when choosing the country to be born in. /s